# Cannot get Facebook Profile Picture Size

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get the size of Facebook user's profile pictures by using the following code:

getimagesize('http://graph.facebook.com/XXXXXXXXXXXX/picture?type=large')

where XXXXXXXXXXXXXX is the Facebook's user ID.

When I tested the code on my local machine, I could get the image size back. However, when I tested on remote server with www.domain.com, the (http://graph.facebook.com/XXXXXXXXXXXX/picture?type=large) return nothing.

What's possible reason of this issue? Can anybody give me some hints?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the error logs? I'm guessing the request isn't being made or the response isn't coming back properly. What version of PHP are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The `getimagesize()` requires that [allow_url_fopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) is set to "1" in php.ini. You may want to check that setting on your remote server.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, it is already open. Is there anything I can check? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Jimmy, the PHP version that does not work is 5.2.17, and the ones works is 5.2.6 and 5.2.4. Do you think this is the issue?